# Rename White tag to TestStack-White

Tags: discussion, retag-request

I just finished cleaning up the questions in the [white](/questions/tagged/white) tag.  43% (56 out of 129) were asking about graphic artifacts or layout problems, not the testing framework.  Changing the tag to the framework's full name would prevent new users from ending up with [white](/questions/tagged/white) in their tag list because they were just shotgunning things into the field and not reading the tag description popup.  Because it's not well known the error apparently wasn't caught during review.

Also setting [white](/questions/tagged/white) as a synonym to [teststack-white](/questions/tagged/teststack-white) would hopefully prevent it from being recreated and accumulating a new collection of garbage.